# Как сгруппировать массив дат по месяцам и годам и показать в tableView?

Tags: swift

Я работаю над приложением для учёта расходов и доходов для iOS.
Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, в tableView появлялась новая секция с месяцем и годом, а в ней дата, которую я выбрал в datePicker. Естественно, если я выберу дату с другим месяцем, создавалась новая секция. Пока у меня получилось группировать даты по нажатию кнопки, но когда я повторно нажимаю на кнопку, секции дублируются.
Вот мой код:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var createButton: UIButton!

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var dateArray: [Date] = []
    var result = [[String]]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    }
    
    func sorted() {
        let sortedDateArr = dateArray.sorted { $0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending }
        var tempArr = [String]()
        for (index, date) in sortedDateArr.enumerated() {
            tempArr.append(formatter.string(from: date))
            if index + 1 < sortedDateArr.count {
                if let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: sortedDateArr[index + 1]).day, days > 1 {
                    result.append(tempArr)
                    tempArr = []
                }
            } else {
                result.append(tempArr)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func createButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        dateArray.append(datePicker.date)
        sorted()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return result.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(result[section].last!)"
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return result[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.labelCell.text = "\(result[indexPath.row][indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит потому что вы не удаляете старые данные из массива `result`, все время добавляя туда новые. Я переработал ваш пример, добавив модели данных для удобства

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    class Record : Comparable {
        
        let calendar: Calendar = {
            var calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
            calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
            return calendar
        }()
        
        var date: Date
        
        init(date: Date) {
            self.date = date
        }
        
        // MARK: Equatable and Comparable for sorting
        
        static func == (lhs: Record, rhs: Record) -> Bool {
            lhs.date == rhs.date
        }
        
        static func < (lhs: Record, rhs: Record) -> Bool {
            lhs.date < rhs.date
        }
        
    }
    
    class Section : Record {
        
        private let formatter: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM"
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
            return formatter
        }()
        
        var title: String {
            formatter.string(from: date)
        }
        
        var items = [SectionItem]()
        
        func addRecord(_ record: SectionItem) {
            items.append(record)
        }

    }
    
    class SectionItem : Record {
        
        private let formatter: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
            return formatter
        }()
        
        var year: Int {
            calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        }
        
        var month: Int {
            calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        }
        
        var title: String {
            formatter.string(from: date)
        }

    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var createButton: UIButton!
    
    var items = [SectionItem]()
    var sections = [Section]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func sortData() {
        
        if items.isEmpty {
            return
        }
        
        // prepare and reset data
        items.sort()
        sections = []

        var year = 0
        var month = 0
        var section: Section!
        
        for item in items {
            
            // create new section for each month in each year
            if section == nil || item.year != year || item.month != month {
                section = Section(date: item.date)
                sections.append(section)
            }
            
            section.addRecord(item)
            year = item.year
            month = item.month
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func createButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateRecord = SectionItem(date: datePicker.date)
        items.append(dateRecord)
        sortData()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].title
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)
А как это можно перенести в Реалм?

Comment: @Rivia это уже другой вопрос, по Realm много мануалов, попробуйте для начала реализовать самостоятельно

Comment: не могу найти, как сохранить Comparable в Realm

Comment: @Rivia а почему дело именно в Comparable?

Comment: class SectionData: Object {
    objc dynamic var title: String?
    var items: [SectionItemData] = []
}
class SectionItemData: Object {
    objc dynamic var year: Int = 0
    objc dynamic var month: Int = 0
    objc dynamic var title: String?

Это правильная модель Реалма?
Я когда пытаюсь в неё сохранить, ругается на Comparable

Comment: @Rivia рекомендую оформить для этого отдельный вопрос с вашим кодом и текстом ошибки

Comment: Вопрос решен, всё просто оказалось)